# Can you explain me Recursion?

Tags: c, recursion

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        reverse(1);
        return 0;
    }

    void reverse(int i)
    {
        if (i > 5)
            exit(0);

        printf("%d\n", i);
        return reverse(i++);
    }
```

How this recursion is working?

When I am running it `1` is printed infinitely. I expected the output to be `12345`

Comment: `return reverse(++i);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when the `++` operator is *after* the variable, it does a "postincrement" oparation, so while it increments the `i` variable just before discarding it, the *expression* result is the *original* value of `i`, so the function is called with the same value every time.

Answer (score 1):

You used `i++` that increments i but uses it's original value in the expression.

```
int a=0   
int b=a++; // a is 1, b is 0
int c=++a; // a and c is 2
int d=a+1; // a is 2 and not changed, d is 3
```

When you are doing recursion you should try not to mutate the variables since it's unnecessary.

```
void reverse(int i)
{
    if (i > 5)
       return;           // instead of exit you could use return.

    printf("%d\n", i);
    return reverse(i+1); // changed from i++ to i+1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you leave the recursive function, value of i remains 1 as you are using post increment operator. use (i+1) instead